# convert cte to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, common-table-expression

i have a recursive cte in mssql which finds all children of a certain node. in db terms:

```
create table nodes (
     id         int primary key autoincrement,
     parent     int
)
```

with this table i had a cte that i used to create a view:

```
create view (
     node_id    int,
     child_id   int
)
```

how do i do that in mysql? (I cannot change the table format to accomodate other methods such as with the nested set model)

worst case, could i make a function to do it?

thanks!

Comment: To convert a normal `cte` just make it into a view but I assume your `cte` was recursive? In which case there is no support in mysql for these. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276136/recursive-self-query/3276806#3276806) for some useful links on the subject of representing hierarchical data in MySQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this discussion:

[How do you use the "WITH" clause in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382573/how-do-you-use-the-with-clause-in-mysql)