# How to order records that are chained together by status fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a table that holds a list of tasks to be performed by a process. Each task only works on items that match the input status, and when the task is completed it changes the item's status to the output status.

To track these tasks I use a table like this.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tasks` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `job_type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `input_status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `output_status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

The task's statuses form a chain of events. Here is an example

```
NULL -> NEW
NEW -> CREATE
CREATE -> INSPECT
INSPECT -> VERIFY
VERIFY -> PUBLISH
```

In real life the list of tasks is very long. *note: The types of different statuses are unknown to me, these user defined values*.

When I view the table using an order of `input_status` the records show the tasks in the wrong order. Sorting by `input_status` and `output_status` also doesn't work (obviously).

How can I sort the table where `null` is first, followed by the chain of `input_status` to `output_status`?

I figure that I'll have to create a virtual field to hold an extra sorting value, but I'm not sure what it should be or calculated.

Here is what I've tried so far, but it doesn't work.

```sql
SELECT *,
    (SELECT input_status FROM tasks AS parent 
        WHERE parent.output_status = tasks.input_status
    ) AS sorted
    FROM tasks
    ORDER BY sorted, input_status;
```

Comment: Oracle uses syntax called connect by prior.  In concept your looking for a hierarchical query, which to my knowledge mySQL doesn't support.  However there are approaches which may meet your need such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104187/mysql-hierarchical-queries or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646833/using-mysql-query-to-traverse-rows-to-make-a-recursive-tree but some of these are risky as they rely on undocumented behaviors to remain constant in upgrades.

Comment: There are two keyfield missing from this (detail) table definition; either a date or versionnumber + an object_id for which this table contains all the statusses. Also: most of the varchar fields don't look fully functional dependent on the PK, and should probably be put into the "master" table

Comment: After some research I found this isn't possible with MySQL. Should I leave the question open or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

You can build a case statement on which you apply the sorting (not sure about the exact syntax however):

```
SELECT * FROM tasks 
    ORDER BY 
        CASE WHEN input_status IS NULL THEN '_' 
        ELSE output_status END ASC;
```

Of course you will have to adapt the case statement to your sorting needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have defined a master relation on status values. If you had done it, query would have been easier.

Master Staus to hold `status_id` and `status_text` (`null`, `new`, `verify`, etc.).
Child `tasks` to to refer from master for input and output status id values.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need a reqursive query to do it. You can consider `output_status` as ID and  `input_status` as a PARENT_ID. So you need to find full PARENT->CHILD path to assign an order number.

It can be done simple in MS SQL with recursive CTE but for MySQL as I know it isn't simple.

[Try to use these UDF's to make sorting field for example [null->stat1->stat2->....]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7147/find-highest-level-of-a-hierarchical-field-with-vs-without-ctes)

Another approach if there is a fixed maximum status count you can do it using LEFT JOIN to connect previous records to find path to sort. Something like this (here are 3 levels of recursion):

```
SELECT tasks.*
    FROM tasks
    LEFT JOIN tasks t1 on t1.output_status=tasks.input_status
    LEFT JOIN tasks t2 on t2.output_status=t1.input_status
    LEFT JOIN tasks t3 on t3.output_status=t2.input_status

ORDER BY tasks.title,t3.output_status,t2.output_status,t1.output_status
```

Also here are links to consider:

- [Recursive self
  query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276136/recursive-self-query)