# Mysql: Get all the linked rows in a table

Tags: mysql, linked-list, hierarchical-data

I have a table structure

kinda like this

```
id  |   title | next 
1   |  test   | 5
2   |  test   | 0
3   |  test   | 0
4   |  test   | 0
5   |  test   | 3
```

Now, as you see 1 points to next item 5 and 5 points to next item 3 and 3 denotes the end

I need a query, from which I can get 1, 5, 3 serially in one column and their title also

like

```
result | title
--------------
1      |  test
5      |  test
3      |  test
--------
```

please help. I dont even know how to get started at such query.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a tree query - check
[Is it possible to query a tree structure table in MySQL in a single query, to any depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169817/is-it-possible-to-query-a-tree-structure-table-in-mysql-in-a-single-query-to-any)

Comment: I saw your link, but I am lost. I dont know how to implement it, in my case. May be a small example.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is join the table on itself.

```
SELECT * FROM `table` AS `child` 
JOIN `table` AS `parent` 
ON `parent`.`next` = `child`.`id`
```

You need to give both copies of the table their own alias (here: parent and child) because otherwise you will run into uniqueness troubles.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a loop that repeats a simple query.. 
I could post an example here. Are you using PHP?