# Get downlines from a particular user in Hibernate or SQL

Tags: sql, hibernate

I have a User table which looks like below

```
UserID  Name    SponsorID (FK)
1       A       null
2       B       1
3       C       1
4       D       3
```

The `SponsorID` refers to `UserID`. Now I need write a query which returns all user who is descendant of a given `UserID`.

Example

1. For UserID 1 the query returns all 4 users
2. For UserID 3 the query should return 1 user

The current implementation is getting the user list by `looping` each direct downline and I am looking for a better  solution if it's possible.

**UPDATE**

Current code

```
public void findDownlineSponsorByUserBO(UserBO rootBO) throws Exception {
    List<UserBO> downlines = businessOperationService.findUserBySponsorId(rootBO.getId(), "createdDate", false);
    memberList.addAll(downlines);
    for (UserBO memberBO : downlines) {
        findDownlineSponsorByUserBO(memberBO);
    }

}
```

Comment: Add your current implementation code.

Comment: updated my question with the current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use an iterative or recursive solution here, unless (perhaps) you're limited to one level of sponsor and can relate UserID to SponsorID in one join. You could load the table into a tree structure in memory, and then query that. Loading it would be O(nlogn), but then traversing it would be O(logn).

This other SO question might give you some useful ideas: [Is it possible to query a tree structure table in MySQL in a single query, to any depth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169817/is-it-possible-to-query-a-tree-structure-table-in-mysql-in-a-single-query-to-an)